# Google Maps distance Matrix API returns different distance

Tags: google-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am using google distanceMatrixApi to calculate distance between source and destination. It is however, giving varying results.

For eg:

Source: [E3B 4R3, CA]
Destination: [V5Y 1V4, CA]

Sometimes, it is returning 5363860, some other times it is returning 5367400. Can someone please tell me why is it not showing consistent results.
Thank you !